# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null after upgrading to WordPress 5.5

Tags: php, javascript, comments, upgrade

I am getting the following error from `comment-reply.min.js` (which seems to be a WordPress file):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
    at comment-reply.min.js?ver=026d5828124b6319675d89d24f212b97:2
    at Object.moveForm (comment-reply.min.js?ver=026d5828124b6319675d89d24f212b97:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.a (comment-reply.min.js?ver=026d5828124b6319675d89d24f212b97:2)
```

Is this a known issue after upgrading to WordPress 5.5 or should I start debugging it?

What would be the best way to address it?

We have not changed the comments template but only upgraded to the latest version of WordPress.

The relevant part of the template is:

```
<?php comment_id_fields($_GET["post_id"]); ?>
<?php do_action('comment_form', $_GET["post_id"]); ?>
            
<div class="fl-comment-form-cancel">
   <?php cancel_comment_reply_link(); ?>
</div>
```

After a quick check, it seems it is searching for an element with the id `wp-temp-form-div`, which does not exist.

And the issue seems to be here:

```
, r = E(h.commentReplyTitleId)
, o = void 0 !== r ? r.firstChild.textContent : "";
```

If `commentReplyTitleId` does not exist, `r` will be `null`, hence different than `undefined`, so it tries to get the `firstChild`.

---

A quick workaround I'm using:

```
(function () {
    var oldGet = document.getElementById.bind(document)
    document.getElementById = function (id) { return oldGet(id) || undefined; }
})();
```

But to me it seems like a bug in 5.5.

Comment: You probably want to be looking [at the unminified version](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.5/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js#L410-L411), but yes I agree that's wrong. I'd change it to `( null != replyElement )`. Go ahead and raise a trac ticket?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in 5.5.1, [commit 48877](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/48877):

> Correct the check for reply element existence in `comment-reply.js.`
>
> `document.getElementById()` returns `null` if no matching element was found, so the previous comparison didn't work as expected.